# Python. How to separate string with whitespace every nth character?

Tags: python

How would you insert a whitespace into a string after every nth term.
I need the output to still be a string, not a list.

This is what i would want it to look like:

```
message = ("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
output = ("xxxxx xxxxx xx") #E.g every 5 characters
```

*edit
my question doesn't involve lists, only strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Comment: My question doesn't involve lists, just strings.

Comment: You can produce string from list pretty simple: ' '.join(your_list)

Comment: There is a possible way to do this, without using any lists, but i don't know how.

Comment: string in python is kind of list, you can operate on string like it's list.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> message = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
>>>' '.join([message[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(message), 5)])
'xxxxx xxxxx xx
```

Comment: Provide additional information rather than a snippet of the code